# Generate AccountId from sr25519::Public

Tags: account

I am trying to run a benchmark for one of the test cases where I need to have some AccountId in storage to check and verify that the origin of the caller exists in storage

I there any way to convert sr25519::Public to AccountId.

```
use sp_io::crypto::{sr25519_generate}

benchmark! {
   set_and_verify {
        let pub_key = sr25519_generate(AURA,None);
        let msg = b"hello";
        let signature:sr25519::Signature= sr25519_sign(AURA,&pub_key,&msg).unwrap();
        let accounts:T::AccounId = vec![pub_key]
         StorageAccounts::<T>::put(&accounts);
    }: _(RawOrigin::Root,(msg.encode(),signature.encode()))
    verify {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general you can't unless `AccountId` is bound to a trait which actually provides you with a conversion function which does what you want.

The `frame_system::Config::AccountId` which I'd presume you're using could easily be a type into which it makes no sense to convert from a S/R25519 public key. For example, in test runtimes, `AccountId` is a `u64`, in a Polkadot runtime, it is `MultiSigner`.

If you don't really care about how it is converted, but you just want some `AccountId` value vaguely associated with the public key, then you might do something like:

```
(0u8, pub_key).using_encoded(|entropy| {
    AccountId::decode(&mut TrailingZeroInput::new(entropy))
        .expect("infinite input; no invalid input; qed")
})
```

This won't necessarily give any kind of sensible value of `AccountId`, but should work ok for the most common of them. It works by ensuring the first byte is zero, which is guaranteed to convert into a sensible enum variant in the case of something like a `MultiSigner` and won't do any harm with something like a `u64`. Be warned though: it won't work in general and it will result in a completely arbitrary and meaningless value of `AccountId`.

The *correct* ways of doing it are a bit more involved and may not be needed if this is just test/benchmarking code. One way involves introducing a more bounded version of `AccountId` into your pallet's `Config` trait, a little bit like the `Event` type which pops up everywhere.

It would be bounded similarly:

```
type AccountId: From<sr25519::Public> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>;
```

Anything of this type (which because of the `IsType` bound now includes the System's `AccountId`) is convertible from an Sr25519 public key.

Another way would be to introduce another type item in the `Config` trait which implements the conversion. It would look something like:

```
type ConvertIntoAccountId: Convert<sr25519::Public, Self::AccountId>;
```

This has the advantage that you don't need to implement `From<sr25519::Public>` for your `AccountId`, which might be difficult or impossible.

Comment: Thank you, @Gav for the detailed answer. It was very helpful and solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can decode the bytes into an accountId using something like this:

```
let accounts = T::AccountId::decode(&mut &pub_key.encode()[..]).unwrap()
```

Comment: This might not work as expected if the `AccountId` is a `MultiSigner` (or indeed anything except `sr25519::Public`).

Answer (score 2):

You can also put a where clause into your benchmark and change your mocked runtime to use real crypto. Bit ugly but works.

```rust
benchmark! {
    where_clause {
        where T::AccountId: From<sp_core::sr25519::Public>,
    }

    …
}
```